# Errors after upgrading to Joomla 3.4.1

Tags: joomla-3.x, upgrade, update

After upgrading from Joomla 3.3 to 3.4.1 -by extracting the Joomla update package- I was checking that all my menu tabs are working correctly. However I am facing two issues:

1. I found that two tabs give me a `404 - Category not found` error. However , when I turn the SEF URL option off , everything works fine. I need them on though.
2. The language switcher module lists the languages as German | English even when German is selected though it should display Deutsch | Englisch.

Any help with that ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't know the answer to the first question, even though I'm facing similar problem with migrated content from J1.5, but for the second question there is known J3.4 bug, which you can find on https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Infinite_error_loop_on_multilanguage_sites which in general needs you to edit and save every content language in Language Manager and ensure it's access level is set to Public.